# Creating "map" from my own image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have my own jpg and I want to do something like that:

[image]

Declare areas, where after click such popup will show up. How can I do this? I've tried with map view, but I don't think that is correct.

Comment: I don't fully understand; what is it exactly you are trying to do? Do you mean you want to put boxes over the jpg like those on youtube?

Comment: Well you need a list of areas and find the current pointer position within them. Or you chop up your full image into areas and and an onclick event handler for each one.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson This is exactly what I'm trying to do, only I don't know how. Which chapter of documentation should I read about choping images or selecting areas of an image?

Comment: @G.Bach I'm trying to split jpg image into clickable areas.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do want to accomplish but you don't provide enough specifics to determine which approach is most appropriate. (e.g. do you need to display these 'hotspot' areas graphically before or after they are clicked, etc.).

To take the most basic approach, you define an array of CGRect-based objects and then in a touch event, test if the touch point is inside any of the rects.

```
// many ways to define the rects
    NSMutableArray* hotspots; //this would be a @property declared elsewhere

// define 5 CGRects
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        NSValue *rectObj = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(i * 10, 0, 44, 44)];
        [hotspots addObject:rectObj];
    }
```

// and to test for hits:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Detect touch anywhere
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    for (NSValue* rectObj in hotspots) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint([rectObj CGRectValue], point)){
            //this is a hit so do something

            break;
        }
    }
}
```